# How to show two different independent objects/classes in one Recycler View?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Is there any way? two independent classes can communicate with single recyclerView...
what i mean actually i have one recyclerView and i have two objects, for instance: one class has "name" and other class has "qualification" something like that, and  both classes extends from AppcompatActivity. I wanna show both these in that one particular recyclerView
**The Case is:**
 I am using Room persistence lib. with MVVM i have one Entity class **personal information** and i am showing all those stuff in recyclerView and working fine. Now i have Button of **objectives** when i press it, it goes to different activity and have to enter some data and have to show in the same recyclerView and that objectives has its own Entity class which belongs to lets say objectivesActivity class..
in short we can say that, there are two Entity classes and two activity classes but one recyclerView which has to show both of their data..

Comment: maybe not...btw whats the use case??

Comment: i have updated my question have a look see

Comment: I think you need to make two adapters like the Amir said

Answer (score 0):

i need more to know about your use case but my general solution is that you can create two adapter and when you want change RV you can just change your adapter.